# Erase inline objects from Docs using Docs API

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to delete the inline embedded images when the id is supplied

I have tried with

```
Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests: [{"deletePositionedObject": {"objectId": "kix.b0ejdj9gt8ia"}}]}, doc.getId());
```

But this will not delete the images inside

Answer (score 0):

### Findings

On my replication, the [DeletePositionedObjectRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletepositionedobjectrequest) produces an error as seen below after inserting an embedded image with an `objectId`:

**The `DeletePositionedObjectRequest` Request:**

[image]

**The Error:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0].deletePositionedObject: No positioned object with ID: kix.ig5lfhg9lak6",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

This looks like the `objectId` needed in `DeletePositionedObjectRequest` is a [positioned object](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletepositionedobjectrequest) & is different from `objectId` of the [inline embedded image](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest).

### Recommendation

As an alternative solution, you can use the [deleteContentRange](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#deletecontentrangerequest) instead & adjust it accordingly to your setup.

### Test Result:

**1.** Get the `startIndex` & `endIndex` of the embedded inline image on the document.

> [image]

**2.** The `deleteContentRange` request body

> [image]

### Sample document before running the request:

> [image]

### Sample Document after:

> [image]